# exporting C local variables : JNI run-time behavior issue

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface, extern, memcpy

I want to export some static variables in C library (libA for instance) to use them from outside in other C file.

I used to use `extern` keyword for the desktop application and it was working, however when
I moved to JNI & Android, the `extern` keyword couldn't do the trick because when trying to build the *.so of the libA, regardless of my other C file (which uses the libA static variables), I got copiler error of "undefined reference" for all of the "extern variables" of libA.

For that, I tried to link the C file when generating the *.so of the libA, but at run time, I noticed that the variables have different addresses which is not the normal result of the `extern` keyword. ( meaning that I'm manipulating different addresses <=> different variables instead of same address <=> "same variable").

So, is there a way to solve this issue ? maybe using memcpy or memset and if it's the proper way, please how to do that ?

Thanks in advance.

B.R

Answer (score 0):

would setting up a environment variable in the JNI file help you out?

E.g:   `setenv("GLOBALVARIABLE", "ON", 1);`

Comment: thanks for answer, however I don't think this can solve the issue. maybe this can be some alternative to generate the *.so, but I don't see how it's going to solve the run-time behavior ( different addresses )